# Importing a png asset to unity. Pixel size is decreased

Tags: unity-game-engine, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to import a png image to unity. It's size reads 2.7 MB and its dimensions are 3999 x 2169. When I `Import New Asset` to the project folder unity says it's 2048 x 1111 and 11.6 MB size.

[image: screenshot side-by-side properties of the image]

I need my image to be 3999x2169 as it is *(because I don't want the player to see any pixels)*. Why does unity scale it down? How come? Any ideas?

*I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 64bit*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Click the texture in the project folder
- In the inspector Search for `Max Size` which will probably be greyed out, because you have to click the `default` tab above it first (or any tab you like and check `override for...`)
- adjust Max Size and hit Apply and you're done!

*Thanks to wiliz at freenode #unity3d*